# Use build.gradle task on githut_actions yaml

Tags: java, gradle, github-actions

I have this task on build.gradle

```
version = "1.2.3"

tasks.register("printVersion") {
    println("version=$version")
}
```

And i can use it on my Jenkinsfile like this:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        VERSION = 'latest'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Read Version') {
            steps {
                script {
                    VERSION = sh(
                        returnStdout: true,
                        script: "./gradlew printVersion | grep version="
                    ).substring(8).trim()
                    echo "Version: $VERSION"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The echo command on Jenkinsfile returns: Version: 1.2.3

Now i'm migrating Jenkinsfile to gh actions, and i can't figured out how to get this version from the task

This is my gh_actions.yaml so far

```
name: GitHub Actions Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - poc_gh_actions

env:
  BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ vars.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Getting git hash
        run: |
          export GIT_HASH=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
          echo $GIT_HASH
      - name: Restore gradle dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: "~/.gradle"
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-modules-${{ hashFiles('**/build.gradle') }}
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'
      - name: Validate Gradle wrapper
        uses: gradle/wrapper-validation-action@ccb4328a959376b642e027874838f60f8e596de3
      - name: Getting build.gradle version
        run: |
          chmod +x gradlew
          ./gradlew printVersion | grep version=
```

I can only run the task, witch returns: version=1.2.3

But i want save it and only the "1.2.3" text on a variable to tag my docker image later

Just to know. Using java 17 and gradle 7.6.1

So far i tried:

```
- name: Getting build.gradle version
  run: |
    chmod +x gradlew
    export VERSION=./gradlew printVersion | grep version=
    echo $VERSION
```

```
- name: Getting build.gradle version
  run: |
    chmod +x gradlew
    export VERSION=latest
    ./gradlew printVersion | grep version= >> $VERSION
    echo $VERSION
```

Comment: See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/manually-migrating-to-github-actions/migrating-from-jenkins-to-github-actions.

Comment: There's one to one mapping Jenkins' `environment` and GHA's job/steps `env`. You can use that for this migration.